# Recursive half equal string

Tags: java, recursion

I'm having trouble building a recursive function in java which returns true if more than half of the characters are equal and false otherwise.
The equal characters must be in the same index.

for example:

```
Imhereman Imhereasd
```

are ok since there are 6 equal characters at 0,1,2,3,4,5 indexes and 6 is bigger than half of the string length.

on the other hand:

```
Imhereman Imhxxisuw
```

Is not ok since there are 3 equal characters at 0,1,2 and 3 is smaller than the half of the string length.

the prototype is :

```
public static Boolean diffp(String s1, String s2);
```

any suggestions?

I only know that I should compare s1[0] and s2[0] and each time "cut" the string with substr().
But how do I count the number of equalities so I know if I should return true or false?

thanks in advance

Comment: This would be simpler if you apply a loop rather than using recursion...

Comment: You could pass it as a parameter to the method.

Comment: Something like `public static Boolean diffp(String s1, String s2, int count)`

Comment: Is this a homework question - in other words, are the constraints "Boolean" and "recursive" a given, and fixed? Because they are not terribly good choices for the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Yea, a challenge question. I know they are not good choices.

Comment: additional function parameters can be added though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the recursive function a "goal" - return true when something happens. The goal is "we need this many characters to match". Every time we find a match we call the function again, but with the parameter reduced by one (one less match needed to be found).

You call it initially with `n = s1.length() / 2`, obviously.

```
class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        System.out.println(checkVal("Imhereman", "Imaereads", 5));
        // your code goes here
    }
    public static Boolean checkVal(String s1, String s2, int n)
    {
        System.out.println("comparing '" + s1 + "' and '" + s2 + "' with n = " + n + " matches to go");
        if(n == 0) return true;
        if(s1.length() == 0 || s2.length() == 0) return false;
        if(s1.charAt(0) == s2.charAt(0)) n--;
        return checkVal(s1.substring(1), s2.substring(1), n);
    }
}
```

Output (including the intermediate print which you obviously will want to remove in the final code - it's there to show what is going on):

```
comparing 'Imhereman' and 'Imaereads' with n = 5 matches to go
comparing 'mhereman' and 'maereads' with n = 4 matches to go
comparing 'hereman' and 'aereads' with n = 3 matches to go
comparing 'ereman' and 'ereads' with n = 3 matches to go
comparing 'reman' and 'reads' with n = 2 matches to go
comparing 'eman' and 'eads' with n = 1 matches to go
comparing 'man' and 'ads' with n = 0 matches to go
true
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class TestClass {
    public static int count = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s1 = "abdefgh";
        String s2 = "abcdepqrs";
        checkVal(s1, s2, 0);
        System.out.println(count);
        if(count>=(s1.length()/2))
        {
            System.out.println("accept");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Dont Accept");
        }

    }

    public static void checkVal(String s1, String s2, int pos) {
        if (pos == s1.length()) {
            return;
        }
        if (s1.charAt(pos) == s2.charAt(pos)) {
            count++;
        }

        checkVal(s1, s2, pos + 1);

    }

}

O/P :
s1="abcdefgh" s2="abcdepqrs"
op: 5
    accept


s1="abcdefgh" s2="abdepqrs"
op: 2
    Dont Accept
```

PS: Please let me know if I have misunderstood the question...